# Deskband (Explorer Bar) Visual Styles

Tags: c++, atl

I have a toolbar inside an explorer bar built with ATL / C++. Everything works great but the visual style applied is a little... dated. From what I read it has to do with pre version 6 commctrl being brought in. My question(s) are:

- Am I on the right track with the pre 6 commctrl issue?
- Any resources you guys have laying around which could give me a wee example?

I've already tried:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' "\ 
"version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

To no avail, I believe this doesn't work due to it not being an application but a DLL pulled in by a process (iexplorer). If that is the case there is also a:

```
//Using ComCtl32 Version 6 in an Application That Uses Extensions, Plug-ins, or a DLL That Is Brought into a Process
```

Located at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649781(v=vs.85).aspx which I am going to try as I post this.

Answer (score 0):

Awkwardly the second bit to my original post resolved my issue:

I'll add the full post from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649781(v=vs.85).aspx below:

> Using ComCtl32 Version 6 in an Application That Uses Extensions,
>   Plug-ins, or a DLL That Is Brought into a Process
>
> The following are examples of applications that use extensions.
>   Microsoft Management Console (MMC) Windows Shell Microsoft Visual
>   Studio ComCtl32.dll version 6 is not completely backward compatible
>   because some of the controls are modified and new controls are added.
>   Using version 6 of the common controls might require code changes in
>   your application. If an application uses extensions developed by a
>   third party, you cannot change the extension if you have compatibility
>   issues. The following steps describe how you can apply a visual style
>   to your application without impacting an extension. To create a
>   manifest and enable your application to use visual styles. Include the
>   common controls header file as follows:

```
#include "commctrl.h"
```

> Compile your application with the -DISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED flag or
>   insert the following statement before the #include "windows.h"
>   statement.

```
#define ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED 1
```

> Add a file called YourApp.manifest to your source tree that uses the
>   XML manifest format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <assembly
 xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
 <assemblyIdentity
     version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication"
     type="win32" /> <description>Your application description here.</description> <dependency>
     <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity
             type="win32"
             name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
             version="6.0.0.0"
             processorArchitecture="X86"
             publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
             language="*"
         />
     </dependentAssembly>
     </dependency>
     </assembly>
```

> Add the manifest to your application's resource file as follows:
>
> ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "YourApp.manifest"
>
> Winuser.rh includes the following defines:

```
 #define RT_MANIFEST 24
 #define ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID 2
```